# How to get exported members using Typescript Compiler API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm working on https://github.com/GooGee/Code-Builder

This is the file that loaded by Typescript Compiler API:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs'
```

This is my code:

```js
function getExportList(node: ts.Identifier, checker: ts.TypeChecker) {
    const symbol = checker.getSymbolAtLocation(node)
    return checker.getExportsOfModule(symbol)
}
```

Trying to get exported members of `fs`.

I know the `symbol` is not a `ts.ModuleSymbol`, it won't work.

Then what should I do?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_nlNL820NL822&ei=CQUoXYHGAqvgkgWYwIzQAg&q=using+js+library+in+typescript&oq=using+js+library+in+typescript&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203.14536.16026..17016...0.0..0.262.856.6j1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i304i39j0i7i30i19j0i8i13i30i19j0i7i30.52PzE1d7dkM#kpvalbx=1) help?

Comment: Recommend tagging these with typescript-compiler-api in the future as you will get a faster response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to get the aliased symbol from the local `fs` symbol that you have there.

```
const localFsSymbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(node)!; // todo: handle when undefined
const fsSymbol = typeChecker.getAliasedSymbol(localFsSymbol);
const moduleExports = typeChecker.getExportsOfModule(fsSymbol);

// this prints out ["rename", "renameSync", "truncate", ...etc...]
console.log(moduleExports.map(s => s.name));
```

If this doesn't work, then ensure there are no diagnostics in the program:

```
const diagnostics = ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program);
console.log(diagnostics);
```

Comment: Thanks a million. That has been bothering me for weeks :)

Comment: @David what should be the possible values of node(passed into getSymbol func)?

Answer (score -2):

Simply Call It

```
this.fs.getExportList(urIdentifier,urTypeChecker)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear before. The `fs` and `getExportList` are not in the same file.

Comment: which place then